# Reflect decorator isn't saving/retrieving data for an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

What am I doing wrong? I have the following decorator functions setup to hold metadata about a class, and they both look like this (one to set the data and one to get the data):

```
function setComponentMenu(text: string): any {
    return Reflect.metadata('componentPath', text);
}
function getMenuPath(target: any): any {
    return Reflect.getMetadata('componentPath', target);
}
```

I am then using it like this, and the `customEditor` decorator works just fine, and puts an instance of the `CameraEditor` class into `Globals.editors`:

```
@customEditor(Camera)
@setComponentMenu('Renderers/Camera')
class CameraEditor extends Editor {

}
```

After the value has been set, and I try to get it back like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < Globals.editors.length; i++){
    let editor: Editor = Globals.editors[i];
    let path = getMenuPath(editor);
    console.log(path);
}
```

I am getting `undefined`, which is fine for items that don't have the `@setComponentMenu` but the `CameraEditor` does have it so I would expect the console to display `Renderers/Camera`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class decorators needs to have the following signature:

```
function decorator(constructor: Function)
```

If you want to pass values to it then you need to use a [decorator factory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories):

```
function setComponentMenu(text: string) {
    return (constructor) => {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you should not return a value for your [class decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) as:

> If the class decorator returns a value, it will replace the class
>   declaration with the provided constructor function.
>
> **NOTE**  Should you chose to return a new constructor function, you must
>   take care to maintain the original prototype. The logic that applies
>   decorators at runtime will not do this for you.

Unless you want to replace the constructor of course.

I wasn't able to make it work using `Reflect.metadata`, but I came up with a working solution using `Reflect.defineMetadata`:

```
function setComponentMenu(text: string) {
    return (constructor) => {
        Reflect.defineMetadata("componentPath", text, constructor, "class");
    }
}

function getMenuPath(target: any): any {
    return Reflect.getMetadata("componentPath", target.constructor, "class");
}
```

You can save the metadata info to the prototype instead of the constructor:

```
function setComponentMenu(text: string) {
    return (constructor) => {
        Reflect.defineMetadata("componentPath", text, constructor.prototype, "class");
    }
}

function getMenuPath(target: any): any {
    return Reflect.getMetadata("componentPath", target.constructor.prototype, "class");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works just perfectly! I used your second example with the prototype, and that does the trick!